# WPF Ribbon IsMinimized take effect only after clicking somewhere on the screen

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

When using

```
MyRibbon.IsMinimized = true;
```

the minimize take effect only after clicking somewhere (anywhenre, even outside the application)

After MyRibbon.IsMinimized = true; and Before clicking somewhere:
[image]

After Clicking anywhere on the screen or even on other place outside the app:
[image]